# how to define radio button CheckedChanged property after finding radio button in another control

Tags: asp.net

i like to know how i have to use radio button CheckedChanged property when the radio button there is in gridview and this gridview itself is inside of 1 user control and user control is inside of detail view control.

before i have learned how i have to find radio button control in another control. but after finding i do not know how to make CheckedChanged property for that?

```
protected void btnShowAddTransmittaltoCon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Transmittallistfortest transmittalList = (Transmittallistfortest)DetailsView1.FindControl("Transmittallistfortest1");
    GridView g3 = transmittalList.FindControl("GridViewTtransmittals") as GridView;
    foreach (GridViewRow di in g3.Rows)

    {

        RadioButton rad = (RadioButton)di.FindControl("RadioButton1");
        //Giving Error:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
        if (rad != null && rad.Checked)
        {
            var w = di.RowIndex;

            Label1.Text = di.Cells[1].Text;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this

```
RadioButton rad = (RadioButton)di.FindControl("RadioButton1");
```

with this:

```
RadioButton rad = di.FindControl("RadioButton1") as RadioButton;
```

You won't get an exception but it may return `NULL` - in which case it'll be caught in the `if`statement: `rad != null`.

The whole point of using the `as` keyword is this:

> as => won't throw an exception - it just reports null.

---

By the way: You should retrieve the `RadioButton` this way:

```
if(di.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    RadioButton rad = di.FindControl("RadioButton1") as RadioButton;
}
```

To define the `CheckedChange` event, do this:

```
//rad.Checked = true;

rad.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(MyCheckedChangeEventHandler);
```

Then define the handler:

```
protected void MyCheckedChangeEventHandler)(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)sender;

    if (rb.Checked)
    {
        // Your logic here...
    }
}
```

Comment: actually my question is how to define radio button CheckedChanged property after finding radio button?

Comment: OK. I thought you were getting an exception since there's a comment in your question. Check the edited answer...